# ¿Cómo mostrar modal al pasar cursos por una imagen?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, css3

Estoy creando una web donde quiero que al pasar el cursor en una imagen aparezca un modal. Lo he logrado realizar pero tengo una complicación, la imagen que se muestra lo realice con un input.
Si no existe el modal y le da clic a la imagen entonces hace una acción, entonces ahora con el modal no me deja presionar dicho botón de la imagen, por que al hacer clic o pasar el cursor me muestra el modal.

Este es mi codigo html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid ">
   <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero_heading text-center">
        <div id="d">
           <div id="c">
             <div id="p">This is a heading This is a heading This is a heading </div>
                <div id="a">
                   <p class="titlechro"></p>
                    <form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
                         <input type="submit" class="po botonconsumo" name="start" id="start"  value="" >
                    </form>
                </div>
              <div id="q"><img src="imgs/botonantojo.png" width="40" height="32" style=""><br>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codigo JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".po" ).hover(function() {
        $('.modal').modal({
        show: true
    });
  });  
});
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El botón es la imagen única que se ve en pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente que quieres resolver, porque el diseño de esa acción es lo que has querido hacer y te funciona. Aún así, por si te sirve de algo, mi apuesta seria por meterle un timeout al evento y así das algo de tiempo antes del modal, de este modo:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  $(".po").hover(
    function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal').modal({
          show: true
        });
      }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  );
});
```

Ya nos diras si es lo que quieres o es otra cosa.

Aquí dejo un snippet funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  $(".po").hover(
    function() {
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.modal').modal({
          show: true
        });
      }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


   <div class="container-fluid ">
   <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero_heading text-center">
        <div id="d">
           <div id="c">
             <div id="p">This is a heading This is a heading This is a heading </div>
                <div id="a">
                   <p class="titlechro"></p>
                    <form action="prueba.php" method="POST">
                         <input type="submit" class="po botonconsumo" name="start" id="start"  value="" >
                    </form>
                </div>
              <div id="q"><img src="imgs/botonantojo.png" width="40" height="32" style=""><br>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ya nos diras si eso te sirve o como pretendías arreglarlo pues.

Comment: Una disculpa por la demora. Funciona lo que comentaste, ya que si el usuario hacerla el mouse al botón, tiene tiempo de presionarlo y si deja el cursos ahí mismo en la imagen entonces aparece dicho Modal. Pero Hay alguna forma en la cual pueda abrirse el modal y poder presionar el botón de dicha imagen?. Esto para que el usuario no espere mucho.

Comment: Creo que no entiendes el concepto del modal.  Por defecto los modales se posicionan sobre **todo** lo que haya en pantalla, y si pulsas fuera de ellos se cierran automáticamente.  Si lo que quieres es que, mientras el modal esté abierto, se pueda pulsar lo que hay debajo, cómo mínimo es raro, pero creo que también es posible modificando las propiedades por defecto del modal, aunque sigo sin verle el sentido.  Y si pones tambien el botón de la imagen en el modal?  Seria quizás más logico así y evitarias comportamientos raros y temporizadores como el que he puesto en mi respuesta

Comment: Otra opción seria hacer la barra del modal movible, es decir, que pudieras agarrar el modal por tltulo y moverlo a otro lugar para ver el botón, pero estariamos en las mismas, cuando quisiera pulsar ese botón se cerraria el modal igualmente.  En la página del manual de bootstrap hay modales de todo tipo, mira a ver si alguno te sirve:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/